# Flask backref returing empty list

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I did ask this question but i am gonna ask it again since didn't get any response

I  am developing a simple flask app with Projects and Tickets tables and they look like following

```
class Projects(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = False)
description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable = False)
created_by_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable = False)
expert_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

def __repr__(self):
    return f"{self.title}"


class Tickets(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100),nullable=False)
    ticket_text = db.Column(db.Text,nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime,nullable=False,default=datetime.utcnow)
    created_by_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    expert_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'),nullable=False)
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id'),nullable=False)
    projects = db.relationship('Projects', backref='ticketso', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Tickets('{self.title}','{self.date_posted}')"
```

Basically it is one Project can have many Tickets but when I query it

```
  @app.route('/project/<project_id>')
  def project(project_id):
  project = Projects.query.get_or_404(project_id)
  return render_template('project.html',title=project.title, project=project)
```

and trying to display it

```
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>{{ project.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ project.description }}</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md">{{ project.created_by_id }}</a></p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">{{ project.ticketso }}</a></p>
  </div>
```

Here `project.ticketso` supposed to return list of tickets assigned to this Project but instead it returns emtpy list

My `tickets.html` page can succecfully display `Project_id` which assigned to that particular ticket

this is how I add `ticket` to the project

```
@app.route('/createTicket',methods=['GET','POST'])
def createTicket():
    users = Users.query.all()
    form = TicketForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
       ticket = Tickets(title=form.title.data,ticket_text=form.ticket_text.data,created_by_id=current_user.username,expert_id= str(form.user_id.data),project_id= str(form.project.data))
       db.session.add(ticket)
       db.session.commit()
       flash('Your ticket has been created', 'success')
       return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('createTicket.html',title='Create a Ticket',form=form, users=users)

@app.route('/createProject',methods=['GET','POST'])
def createProject():
    users = Users.query.all()
    form = ProjectForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        project = Projects(title = form.title.data, description = form.description.data, created_by_id = current_user.username, expert_id = str(form.user_id.data))
        db.session.add(project)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('You project has been created', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('createProject.html',form = form, users = users)
```

EDIT:
I am gonna ask this question different way in order to make it clear.

```
class Person(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
   addresses = db.relationship('Address', backref='person', lazy=True)

class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'),
        nullable=False)
```

The code above I got from flask documentation https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/

It states

```
backref is a simple way to also declare a new property on the Address class. You can then also use my_address.person to get to the person at that address
```

So I can access to the `person` who is in that `address`, but how do we access to the list of `addresses` that `person` has. Because it is `one to many relationship`, it means `one person` can have many `addresses` correct? how do we access them?

Comment: I am confused... What are you trying to do? What column are you trying to find? You are trying to find `Tickets` of the user by their `Projects`?

Comment: Can you show us how you add a new object to the table too?

Comment: @Patch I am trying to find list of tickets that assigned to the project

Comment: @Patch, Thank you I've updated the question, please check it out

Comment: Ok and where do you add the projects?

Comment: @Patch  Sorry just added it, please take a look

Comment: It doesn't work because you don't "point" the Project class to the tickets class. I'll upload an answer later this day if you still need it. Perhaps you should look up on how to do one to many relationships again

Comment: @Patch I tried many ways but still doesn't work, yes please update an answer, I will wait for it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "connect" between the 2 tables. You don't need to define `expert_id` when you create a row. instead you need to point to the `Tickets` Table by the `backref` you set.
Change this line

```
project = Projects(title = form.title.data, description = form.description.data, created_by_id = current_user.username, expert_id = str(form.user_id.data))
```

To this:

```
project = Projects(title = form.title.data, description = form.description.data, created_by_id = current_user.username, ticketso=form)
```

assuming `form` is the Tickets object you want to point to. Then, you'll be able to get the ID of the `Tickets` with `expert_id`

basically, this line `projects = db.relationship('Projects', backref='ticketso', lazy=True)`  creates a "virtual column" in the table you set. In this case is the `Projects` table (You can also access the `Projcts` table from `Tickets` by using the relationship column). Also this two columns are useless. I assume you know how you can access the data without them.

```
expert_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'),nullable=False)
project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id'),nullable=False)
```

Comment: I did everything exact the same as you showed above. In project.html i am using jinja to display list of ticket : {{project.ticketso}} and it is still giving me empty list. I've also tried {{project.ticketso.title}} still no result.

Comment: I am using expert_id because to get a relationship with Users column

Comment: expert_id is a user that ticket assigned to. it has nothing to do with the project, I have updated my post after 'EDIT' ,  it is probably me who is not clear on the question , please take a look on that maybe that makes it clear

Comment: @MuhammedTech I didn't see it was the user that the ticket is assigned to. You can access the list of projects that a ticket has by printing `ticket_obj.projcets`. Also create a `expert_tick = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tickets.id'))` column in `procjets` and it should work.

Comment: I believe that will work, i will try it now. However, what type of relationship that will be? Aren't we use db.ForeignKey on 'Many' side which in my case is 'Tickets' and it already have  project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.id'),nullable=False) and now if I add a new db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tickets.id')) on Project will it still be one-to-many relationship?

Comment: @MuhammedTech Your 'Many' side is `Projects` not `Tickets`. Where ever you create the relationship column is where you want your "one" to be and the ForeginKey to 'many'. That's what I told you to delete both of the lines. If you don't want that just change it according to what I said before.